# How do I search for a replacement home wired only router with NAT and internal DHCP?

Tags: networking, router

I have a ailing home router (specifically a LinkSys/Cisco BEFSR81 Router) which contains NAT and internal DHCP.  I'm looking to replace it but all I am finding is Routers containing Wireless functionality that I do not need.  I want GBit connectivity on all the ports however.

I am thinking that I must be missing some term in my searching unless Wired ONLY NAT home routers have become obsolete in the home consumer market.

So what search terms should I be using to find what I want?

I would ask for specific product recommendations but I know that is basically off limits here.

Comment: Wired-only routers are increasingly rare.  Perhaps choose a few brands you trust and go through their offerings directly.  Otherwise, get a wireless one and turn off the radios.

Comment: @Paul, got any ideas as to vendors that I might search on?

Comment: @Paul are the wireless routers w/o radio any better than going with a wired only router?

Comment: @mdpc Why do you prefer a router without wireless? The price/performance is going to be worse because it will be a niche product rather than a mainstream one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I first do not need the radio, and second w/o the radio I thought it would be cheaper for a relatively good quality item.

Comment: @mdpc It won't be cheaper because the demand is so much lower.

Comment: BTW, I found a candidate made by Cisco.